# Dynamic dropdown list in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKhGd.png)I have next structure of data: district_id and store_type, each district can have multiple values of store_type.
Is it possible in Google Sheets to make next functionality:

In the cell I write district_id, after which all the names of the store_types are displayed in the next cell in the dropdown. I need a solution that will work for a large number of lines.

I found solutions that will help to make that functional only for static data

Answer (score 0):

I have done some research and found this [article](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/dynamic-dependent-drop-down-list-in-google-sheets/) that I think will be helpful for you. Based on the article, this is the formula that is used:

```
=BYROW(E1:E,LAMBDA(rws,IFNA(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(B2:D,B1:D1=rws)))))
```

Note: You can adjust the ranges in the formula and data validation depends on your data. I tried to replicate it on my end and add more data in column D and it transposes the data to column G and onwards.

### Output:

[image: dynamicdropdown]